# Ship Python Extension that required dynamic linking

Tags: python, dynamic-linking, python-extensions

I am writing a c extension (called `my_ext`) and I successfully compiled the source code to a .so file. However, `my_ext` depends another dynamic library installed by pip. So the link directory looks like `<virtual_env>/lib/python3.6/site-packages/foo`. And my link command looks like this `g++ -fPIC -L<virtual_env>/lib/python3.6/site-package/foo/ -lfoo ...` and I am able to link successfully. However, my question is that since my link_directory is hard-coded according to path in my laptop. When I package my python package and ship to customer, how will that extension load libfoo.so? I assume it will look for the path hard-coded by me right? In this case, customer might not be able to load libfoo.so. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> However, my question is that since my link_directory is hard-coded according to path in my laptop

It *shouldn't* be. How did you come to conclusion that it is?

Run `readelf -d my_ext.so`, and see if there is a reference to the path on your laptop. If there is (unlikely), update your question with the output from `readelf -d`, and a better answer may come.

Comment: I figure it out. I just bundled all so file into my wheel package and use RPATH to indicate search path.